# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'login' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I have created register table as below:

```
 create table register(rid int,email varchar(30),name varchar(30),phone varchar(12),address varchar(50),primary key(rid,email));
```

and when I tried to create login table i got errno:150

```
 create table query_login(lid int primary key auto_increment,email varchar(30) not null,salt varchar(100),password varchar(100),foreign key (email)references query_register(email) on delete cascade on update cascade);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got the answer. I just create an index on email